# Json serializing in C++ (ESP32)

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32, arduinojson

I'm writing some script for ESP32 and struggling to serialize a json.

Used libraries are HTTPClient and ArduinoJson.

```
String payload = http.getString();
Serial.println(payload);
deserializeJson(result, payload);
const char* usuario = result["user"];
Serial.println("##########");
Serial.println(usuario);
```

The received payload is:

`{"ip":"10.57.39.137","area":"[{\"id\":\"3\",\"text\":\"BOX\"}]","user":"[{\"id\":\"6270\",\"text\":\"ANDRE LARA OLIVEIRA E SILVA\"}]","teamId":6,"id":4,"siteId":2,"userCreate":"100059527","dateCreate":"2020-11-19T08:49:03.957","userUpdate":null,"dateUpdate":null}`

I need to retrieve id and text from "user" key. It's fine to deserialize and retrieve user object. But `result["user"]` returns:  `[{"id":"6270","text":"ANDRE LARA OLIVEIRA E SILVA"}]` to the char array. So it's something like a json nested in an array... and it's not working out to deserialize.

Can anyone help me how to properly get the "id" and "text" values from "user" object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library doesn't know the content of that string is valid JSON, so you have re-parse it. This code worked for me on my PC, though I don't have an Arduino to test it on:

```cpp
auto payload = "..."; // JSON content here
StaticJsonDocument<1024> result;
deserializeJson(result, payload);
auto user = result["user"].as<const char*>();

StaticJsonDocument<256> userObj;
deserializeJson(userObj, user);
auto id = userObj[0]["id"].as<int>();
auto text = userObj[0]["text"].as<const char*>();
```

Answer (score 0):

*"Can anyone help me how to properly get the "id" and "text" values from "user" object?"* You can access them with

```
const char *id = result["user"]["id"];
const char *text = result["user"]["text"];
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas. I already tried this approach but it returns me blank. Bad thing about my hardware is that i dont have a debugging interface. so im limited to serial printing.

Comment: @alosbh What's the nesting level?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
const int id = result["user"]["id"];
const char* text = result["user"]["text"];
```

Comment: Thank you ocrdu. I already tried this approach but it returns me blank. Bad thing about my hardware is that i dont have a debugging interface. so im limited to serial printing.